# netTiers database schema backwards compatibility

Tags: .nettiers

I've found that the netTiers generated code relies on an exact database schema and is very unforgiving with variations. For example, adding a column to an existing table - if a column is added somewhere in the middle of the table you will see a cast error at runtime unless netTiers is recompiled. This is because the columns are accessed by ordinal and not by name. (Looking through the change log I see that this was done as a performance improvement)

This hasn't been a problem in the past, but on my current project we are trying to build a system with zero downtime upgrades. The challenge we have is database upgrades and it would be great if we could update the database without affected the code.

Has anyone using netTiers had similar problems or looked into similar requirements?

Would altering the templates to access the columns by name be more tolerant of previous schema versions? If so, for me I think this would be worth a minor hit to performance (3% is quoted here [DataReader ordinal-based lookups vs named lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860519/datareader-ordinal-based-lookups-vs-named-lookups))

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted, .NetTiers uses ordinal based lookups in the DataReader. The only way to get .NetTiers to play nicely, is to always add new columns to the end of existing tables, and never restructure the table field order.

By doing this, your v1 code will still work against a table that has a new column appended at the end of the table, whilst your v2 code will work with the new addition.